# How to fix bracket expansion when creating folders using a variable

Tags: variables, mkdir, curly-braces, expansion

​
I'm a novice user trying to do:

```
FoldersToCreate="folder1/subfolder,folder2,folder3,folder4"
mkdir -p /mnt/user/public/test/{$FoldersToCreate}
```

which ends up making these folders:

- {folder1

  - subfolder,folder2,folder3,folder4}

I've read up and learnt about bracket expansion, but I can't find a solution to my problem.  Help please.

Thanks in advance.​

Answer (score 0):

Sharing an answer I found elsewhere, just in case anyone else is looking:

```
FoldersToCreate=\{"Folder1/SubFolder","Folder2","Folder3","Folder4"\}
eval mkdir -p /mnt/user/public/test/"$FoldersToCreate"
```